# When the location and name is changed, the script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This the working  script.

```js
 $.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com', function(data) {
    var text = `Date: ${data.date}<br>
                Time: ${data.time}<br>
                Unix time: ${data.milliseconds_since_epoch}`
                
    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mypanel"></div>
```

In the above script I replaced the URL as `http://abacusshopee.biz/COMPUTERS/test.json` then the Code is not working.

The contents of the JSON file as follows.

```
{
   "date": "09-02-2020",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1599029414853,
   "time": "06:50:14 AM"
}
```

I used same json files for fetching data. Both the files contains. same data.

My problem is that when test with the first script, it is working. But when try with the second one (using 'http://abacusshopee.biz/COMPUTERS/test.json') the script not working.

Comment: Please start with basic debugging. Your browser usually tells you exactly what's wrong. In this case it is a cross-origin request issue: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://abacusshopee.biz/COMPUTERS/test.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

Comment: Thanks. Will you suggest how to solve cross-origin request issue?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue. It is a CORS issue. I have changed the url as 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://abacusshopee.biz/COMPUTERS/test.json'. The test.json file opened via proxy link https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com.

Thanks for comments.